# Custom validation cannot include spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, whitespace

In my Ruby on Rails application I am using custom validation, and have tried to ensure that there are no spaces in a string with this code:

`record.errors[field] << "First name cannot include spaces" if value.gsub(/\s+/, "")`

But it does not work as if I enter some text with no spaces the error still appears, is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `gsub`, rather `match`.

`gsub` will return the string without the space, which is truthy in Ruby.

`match` will return the matched string if it's present and nil if it's not. nil is falsey.

```
record.errors[field] << "First name cannot include spaces" if value.match(/\s+/)
```

Comment: change the condition to regular_expression.match(value). that way it'll work for `nil` values too.

Answer (score 0):

@evanbikes answer is correct, but a minor syntax correction (to possibly save you some headaches in the future):

```
record.errors.add(field, "First name cannot include spaces") if value.match(/\s+/)
```

just in case the Rails guys choose to change the storage mechanism used for errors in the future.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add